# MagTek uDynamo and Unimag SDK - Android

Tags: android, cordova, unimag

I am trying to develop an Android app that is compatible with both the MagTek uDynamo (audio jack card reader) SDK and the Unimag card reader SDK. I'm not sure if there is an SDK out there that would support both of these devices, but here I am.

Both of the demo's for these SDK's work perfectly fine, but integrating the two is confusing me. Does anyone have any experience with these two card reading devices?

I am build this as a Cordova project. So my main class "MagSwipe" extends "CordovaPlugin." I'm not sure how to work around this as both the MagTek and Unimag classes work off of a class that extends "Activity."

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever make progress on this project? I am in need of doing something similar and any information you may have would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the way to go is to be able to detect which device is connected. Include both SDKs in your project. Then before processing for a swipe, detect which device is plugged in(Magtek or Unimag).

After detection of device, force your activity to use relevant SDK and code block.

Hope I got your question right.
Good luck.